# XML Schema can an element have multiple datatypes?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an element in my XML file that can have the value of either decimal or date. In the XML schema for validation, I have specified it as:

```
<xs:element name = "data" type="xs:decimal"/>
```

or I can specify it as `type="xs:date"`.

This only validates it as date or decimal. Is there another datatype or something that will allow me to validate this element regardless of whether it has a date or decimal value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="data">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:date xs:decimal" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```